# 0x80131513 in Asp.net razor editor

Tags: visual-studio, razor, compiler-errors

> HRESULT: 0x80131513 'Method does not exist'

This error shows in create view in asp.net in visual studio 2017.

How can this be resolved?

Comment: Maybe you could give some context, provide a code snippet if possible so it's easier to diagnose.

Comment: http://s8.picofile.com/file/8322895434/Upload.PNG
I want to add a new view.but this error display me can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem once.
check the directory of `razor editor` to be exactly the same in your IDE.
if all your requirements are ok that must be the problem.
hope it works out:)